# $f$ and $g$ are holomorphic function , $A=\{z:{1\over 2}<\lvert z\rvert<1\}$, $D=\{z: \lvert z-2\rvert<1\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ and $g$ are holomorphic function defined on $A\cup D$

$A=\{z:{1\over 2}<\lvert z\rvert<1\}$, $D=\{z:\lvert z-2\rvert <1\}$

1. If $f(z)g(z)=0\forall z\in A\cup D $ then either $f(z)=0\forall z\in A$ or $g(z)=0\forall z\in A$
2. If $f(z)g(z)=0\forall z\in D $ then either $f(z)=0\forall z\in D$ or 
   $g(z)=0\forall z\in D$
3. If $f(z)g(z)=0\forall z\in A\cup D $ then either $f(z)=0\forall z\in A\cup D$ or $g(z)=0\forall z\in A\cup D$
4. If $f(z)g(z)=0\forall z\in A $ then either $f(z)=0\forall z\in A$ or 
   $g(z)=0\forall z\in A$

   Except The $1,3$, I can say $2,4$ are true beacuse of Identity Theorem right? zeroes of holomorphic function are isolated. for $3$ I can define $f(z)=z$ on $A$ and $0$ on $D$ and $g(z)=0$ on $A$ and $z^2$ on $D$

Comment: 1 is a consequence of 4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the identity theorem, but since that theorem doesn't directly apply to products, you should explain *how* you use the identity theorem.

You can, for example, argue that if $f\cdot g = 0$ on some connected open set $S$, then there are $S_1,S_2$ with $f = 0$ on $S_1$, $g = 0$ on $S_2$, $S_1 \cap S_2 = \emptyset$ and $S_1 \cup S_2 = S$. Now if $f$ isn't identically zero on $S$, then due to the identity theorem $S_1$ contains only isolated points, hence for every $x \in S_1$ you have that $B_\epsilon(x) \setminus {x} \subset S_2$ for some $\epsilon > 0$. Using the identity theorem again, you get $g = 0$ on $S$. The same applies with $f$ and $g$ reversed, thus at least one of them is identically zero on $S$.

This works, as you correctly stated, for (2) and (4). As Robert Isreal commented, you get (1) from (4), and for (3) your counter-example indeed refutes the assertion.